# Debian Jessie: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting

Tags: dpkg

When i do a

```
apt-get upgrade
```

i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 : Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) but it is not installed or
                                   linux-initramfs-tool
                          Recommends: firmware-linux-free (>= 3~) but it is not installed
                          Recommends: irqbalance but it is not installed
```

When i then try

```
apt-get -f install
```

It tells me

```
Selecting previously unselected package initramfs-tools.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-base' missing; assuming         package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-4.8-base:amd64' missing;    assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-modules' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'findutils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package `liberror-perl' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can i fix this?
I tried uninstalling those packages. Did not help because i cant.

Comment: Does `/var/lib/dpkg/info` contain anything?

Comment: Yes. Quiet a lot...

Comment: what gives `grep -P -r '^[ \t]*[^#[ \t]+'   /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache policy initramfs-tools` ?

Comment: initramfs-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.120+deb8u2
  Version table:
     0.120+deb8u2 0
        500 http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages

Answer (score 2):

Your package database seems to be badly messed up. You should re-install the affected packages:

```
apt-get --reinstall install perl-base gcc-4.8-base perl-modules perl findutils liberror-perl initramfs-tools
```

You can add any others which turn up in error messages.

If `liberror-perl` is too messed up for `apt-get` to work, try:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb
dpkg -i liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb
```

although if the last "fatal error" in `dpkg` really is as bad as it sounds, you'll need to do the above from a rescue system (mount your file systems under `/mnt` in the rescue system, then run `dpkg --root=/mnt -i liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb`).

Comment: I encountered the error message in the original question today after attempting `apt-get dist-upgrade` with `jessie-backports` in `sources.list`.  I removed  `jessie-backports` from the `sources.list` and ran the `apt-get --reinstall install ...`.  System now updates successfully.

Comment: @RobertL that’s unrelated to the issues here; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508728/86440) for details.